# Google Hangout button on webpage - invite parameters not working

Tags: android, google-hangouts, google-app-invites

currently trying out the Google Hangout Button on a webpage, followed the instructions on this page...
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button

1. Click Button on Desktop chrome - Launches a new browser and hangout invites works correctly...
2. Click Button on Android chrome - problems I'm facing:

2a. Launches Hangout app (works for Hangout App ver8.0.11x ) 
If your phone has updated Hangout App ver12.0.13x, you will be shown the Download  screen and have to tap on 'OPEN' button to launch the app.
2b. Invite parameters not working. After Hangout App launches, it doesn't do anything afterwards, I cannot even invite any other user.

Does the Google Hangout Button work on mobile webpage iOS/ Android?